# Predicting inputs in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Is it possible to predict inputs in "Keras neural network" for a particular output?

For example, I have a dataset with **28 inputs** and **3 outputs**. So, I have trained the model in Keras which works fine. Now, I have to enter the particular values in outputs and I have to predict that what will be the inputs for that particular output.

Comment: Use your `inputs` as `outputs` and `outputs` as `inputs`?

Comment: Considering neural networks mostly consist of matrix multiplications you could 'undo' a layer by subtracting bias to the output and multiplying it by transpose of weights, but theres no way you could undo some operations like convolution, relu acivation etc. You have to train separate network with input/output reversed

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to solve? If you are trying to find the inputs where their predicted output is closest to your pre-defined outputs, then you could use optimization methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question correctly, but if you're trying to build a model that can take inputs and predict outputs, then you will need to train a second model to predict inputs from outputs, where you swap the inputs and outputs so that outputs are your inputs, and your inputs are the outputs. Although this might be annoying, you might have to build a separate network to predict each of your input variables.

To get around this problem, you can consider `autoencoders` if you're okay with getting a close approximation of the input. An autoencoder is an unsupervised artificial neural network that learns how to efficiently compress and encode data then learns how to reconstruct the data back from the reduced encoded representation to a representation that is as close to the original input as possible (you can read more here: https://towardsdatascience.com/auto-encoder-what-is-it-and-what-is-it-used-for-part-1-3e5c6f017726).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is definitely possible to predict inputs from the output. In fact, what you're describing is essentially an autoencoder.

Let's say you have a NN trained on MNIST. If you then use the outputs of the classification layer to train the decoder of an auto encoder, you will get a rough indication of the input.

However this is not the best way to do it. The best way to do it is to simply have the latent space be considered the "output", then feed this output into:

a): A 1 layer classification to give you the predicted output and

b): the decoder

This will give you the predicted output and the original image